# Unique items in a list with condition

Tags: python

If i have a list in python say

```
thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[20,0],[30,1,1]]
```

I would want to have a resulting list

```
thing = [[20,1,1],[20,0,2],[30,1,1]]
```

That is if the first element is the same, remove duplicates and give priority to the number 1 in the second element. Lastly the 3rd element must also be unique to the first element.

In this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827536/django-template-not-iterating-through-list) we solved a complicated method where for a transaction it details a purchased unit. I want to output other units in that course. If two transactions exist that relate to two units in one course it will display them a duplicate (or times each subsequent unit).

The aim of this question it to ensure that this duplication is stopped. Because of the complication of this solution it has resulted in a series of question. Thanks for everyone that has helped so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get unique items from list of lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926928/get-unique-items-from-list-of-lists)

Comment: No this is different as you can see we are looking at the individual values in a multidimensional list.

Comment: use sets to remove duplicates, but sets come with a disadvantage as it's not ordered however there's a geeky function yourset.oderedDict() or something to order it or so(not sure but check on pythons official documentation for sets)

Comment: I am ok with no ordering as i will use a for loop and an id statement on the first element in display. My problem is the duplication. Not my strongest point, so it would be awesome and point worthy if someone made a cool loop for me. Thanks

Comment: @AlexStewart: So you not only want to make the items unique, you also want to reorder them? I wonder why for your example you would expect `[[20,1,1],[20,0,2],[30,1,1]]` instead of `[[20,1,1],[20,0,1],[30,1,1]]`.

Comment: "..if the first element is the same, remove duplicates.." do you mean 'merge' two sublists if they have the same length and their first elements are the same[, where max value of two values gets priority during the merge]?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe thanks for your interest, no ordering is required.

Comment: @RussW So if the first element is the same remove all duplicates where there exists 0 in the second element. Apologies for the complication.

Comment: Shouldn't resulting list be `thing = [[20,1,1],[30,1,1]]`? Why you save `[20,0,2]` element? And what about third element? Where should it come from?

Comment: @twil the last element must also be unique. I know its complicated.

Comment: @AlexStewart: You wrote `give priority to the number 1 in the second element` - what happens if the second element is, say, 2? or 3?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, just edited to add further clarification that the third element must be unique to the first element.

Comment: @AlexStewart: What does `to be unique to the first element` mean? No two lists with the same first element may have the same third element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you would like this, but it works with your example:

```
[list(i) + j for i, j in dict([(tuple(x[:2]), x[2:]) for x in sorted(thing, key=lambda x:len(x))]).items()]
```

EDIT:

Here a bit more detailed (note that it fits better to your description of the problem, sorting ONLY by the length of each sublist, may not be the best solution):

```
thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[20,0],[30,1,1]]
dico = {}
for x in thing:
    if not tuple(x[:2]) in dico:
        dico[tuple(x[:2])] = x[2:]
        continue
    if tuple(x[:2])[1] < x[1]:
        dico[tuple(x[:2])] = x[2:]

new_thing = []
for i, j in dico.items():
    new_thing.append(list(i) + j)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for input `thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[20,1,2]]`, output should be `[[20, 1, 2], [20, 1, 1]]` and your solution gives `[[20, 1, 2], [20, 0, 2]]`

Comment: @RomanPekar I think it do have to return [[20, 1, 2], [20, 0, 2]]... but I can be missunderstanding something...

Comment: `[list(i) + j for i, j in {tuple(x[:2]): x[2:] for x in sorted(thing, key=len)}.items()]` would be a cleaner version of the original list comprehension.

Comment: I don't know, may be it's my English, by I see a "give priority to the number 1 in the second element" in the description of the question. Your solution doesn't check for this condition.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using the `unique_everseen` function from the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

As a first step, here is a solution excluding `[20, 0]`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[30,1,1]]

thing.sort(key=lambda x: 0 if x[1] == 1 else 1)

print(list(unique_everseen(thing, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))))
```

Output:

```
[[20, 1, 1], [30, 1, 1], [20, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: That ignores the requirement to put priority for items with `i[1]==1`.

Comment: @simon, i really like this solution except the priority to '1' is absent.

Comment: Updated for this requirement.

Comment: @Simon thanks for your help, your solution is long winded, however does work. Check out the two ones at the top they are short and i assume less resource intensive.

Answer (score 2):

```
thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[20,0,1],[30,1,1]]

d = {}
for e in thing:
    k = (e[0], e[2])
    if k not in d or (d[k][1] != 1 and e[1] == 1):
        d[k] = list(e)

print d.values()

[[20, 0, 2], [30, 1, 1], [20, 1, 1]]
```

if you don't need initial list:

```
thing = [[20,0,1],[20,0,2],[20,1,1],[20,0,1],[30,1,1]]

d = {}
for e in thing:
    k = (e[0], e[2])
    if k not in d or (d[k][1] != 1 and e[1] == 1):
        d[k] = e

thing = d.values()

[[20, 0, 2], [30, 1, 1], [20, 1, 1]]
```

if you want to keep order of your lists, use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
```

Comment: Roman Pekar this solution is so elegant! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Apologies Roman, there exists two working solutions, and fransua's was the first one given, so i have to give the accepted solution based on that merit.

Comment: no prob, Alex, but I don't think that fransua's solution works for arbitrary input of given problem. Also I think that long list/dictionary comrehensions is less readable and maintainable that simple loops

Comment: I am just implementing the solution now. Will let you know how i go.

Comment: Both solutions work, but yours maintains order. Thanks Roman, awesome job.

Comment: No, my solution doesn't maintains order. wait a sec, I'll add an option to maintain an order